# Windows opened by git-bash appear in the background

Tags: windows, git

When starting new processes from git-bash, new windows are created below all the others, forcing me to access them by Alt-Tab'ing through all my other windows (or using the mouse).

For instance:

- `git rebase -i` from `git-bash` correctly starts Notepad++, but in the background
- `git gui` correctly start git-gui, but in the background
- `explorer` : same

However:

- `gitk` from `git-bash` starts gitk in the foreground
- `explorer` from `cmd` starts explorer in the foreground
- same from PowerShell, all commands work

So, it seems to happen only in git-bash, but not always, and it started around my upgrade to Windows 11.

I already tried setting ForegroundLockTimeout to 0, but it doesn't change the issue.

Comment: Are you using the new "Windows Terminal"?

Comment: No, I'm using git-bash directly

Comment: I'm noticing this too, in particular when I `git commit` which pops up VS Code in the background, and `git difftool` which pops up Beyond Compare in the background with a blinking button. I didn't have this issue in Windows 10. Did you ever find a solution for Windows 11?